# windowShouldClose event not triggered after setting delegate

Tags: swift, macos, nsview, nswindow

I need to check if the user has clicked the close button and show an alert before closing the form.If the user selects an option the program should not be terminated. For this, I'm doing the following

Setting the delegate in `viewDidAppear()`

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSWindowDelegate {
   override func viewDidAppear() {
        self.view.window?.delegate = self
    }
}
```

This is the `windowShouldClose` event, but this is not getting triggered.

```
func windowShouldClose(_ : Any) -> Bool {
     //dostuff 
     }
```

Comment: Did you try the *original* signature `windowShouldClose(_ sender: NSWindow) -> Bool`?

Comment: @vadian Thanks.This solved the issue.